# error with PDFBox in servlets

Tags: servlets, pdfbox

**iam trying to generate a pdf of my page contents from doPost method. but my tomcat server fails to start each time

below is my code

```java
@SuppressWarnings({ "deprecation", "resource" })
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {

        try{
            String filename="mypdf";
            PDDocument mydoc=new PDDocument();
            PDPage page=new PDPage();

            mydoc.addPage(page);

            PDPageContentStream content=new PDPageContentStream(mydoc, page);

            content.beginText();
            content.setFont(PDType1Font.COURIER_BOLD, 30);
            content.moveTextPositionByAmount(250, 750);
            content.drawString("syllabus");
            content.endText();

            content.close();
            mydoc.save(filename);
            mydoc.close();

            System.out.println("the pdf saved at"+System.getProperty("user.dir"));



        }catch(IOException ie)
        { 
            System.out.println("IOexception"+ie);
        }
    }
```

**

Comment: What's the log message?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. just try formatting like this.

```
@SuppressWarnings("javadoc")
public class Billing extends javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet implements javax.servlet.Servlet {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
    performTask(request, response);
}
protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {
    performTask(request, response);
}
private void performTask(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException,
        IOException {

        //Create pdf
        PDDocument document = new PDDocument();

        //Create Page
        PDPage page = new PDPage();

        //Adding the page
        document.addPage(page);


       //Loading the page
       File file = new File("D:/akash/my_doc.pdf");
       //writing text
       contentStream.beginText();
       contentStream.newLineAtOffset(295, 757);
       contentStream.setFont(PDType1Font.HELVETICA_BOLD, 12);
       contentStream.showText("CHIMERA TRANSPLANT RESEARCH FOUNDATION");
       contentStream.endText();

       //Saving the document
       document.save("D:/akash/my_doc.pdf");


       //Closing the document
        document.close();
}
}
```